# Combine plain SQL and DSL in SQL query in jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a complex plain SQL query (with subselects, multiple joins, database specific functions) but I would like to use the jOOQ's DSL for generating e.g. the order by clause.

What I would like to achieve is:

```
DSL
    .using(datasource)
    .select("select column from table")
    .orderBy(DSL.fieldByName("column"))
```

which jOOQ could be transforming to:

```
select * (select column from table) q order by q.column;
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. The following is possible:

```
DSL.using(datasource, dialect)
   .select()
   .from("(select column from table) t")
   .orderBy(DSL.field("t.column"));
```

You have to wrap (and depending on the SQL dialect, also rename) your derived table explicitly yourself.

Note that I'm using [`DSL.field()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-java.lang.String-), not [`DSL.fieldByName()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#fieldByName-java.lang.String...-), as the latter produces a case-sensitive `column` reference. Your plain SQL query would then also have to produce a case-sensitive `column` reference.